# Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AwsSnsService (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am trying to inject a service from one module to another module. I am keep on getting

`Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AwsSnsService (?). Please make sure that the argument function() {\n if (klass !== Object) {\n return klass.apply(this, arguments);\n }\n } at index [0] is available in the AwsModule context.`

Below is the code

aws-sns.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AwsSnsService {
  constructor(private readonly awsSNS: AWS.SNS) {}
}
```

aws.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AwsSnsService } from './aws-sns.service';

@Module({
  providers: [AwsSnsService],
  exports: [AwsSnsService],
})
export class AwsModule {}
```

I want to use the AwsSnsService in my User module. I am doing it in a following way

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    SomeOtherModule,
    AwsModule,
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserDevicePushTokensService],
  exports: [UserService, UserDevicePushTokensService],
})
export class UserModule {}

@Injectable()
export class UserDevicePushTokensService {
  constructor(private readonly awsSnsService: AwsSnsService) {}
}
```

Looks to me the dots are connected in the proper way. Still I am not figuring it out.

Comment: Is `AWS.SNS` a Nest provider? That's where it seems to fail.

Comment: @BunyamiN No it's not a nest provider. May be you are right this could be an issue

Answer (score 2):

You must resolve dependency for   AWS.SNS in AwsSnsService

Example with my s3, the same for SNS and any service:

s3.provider.ts

```
export const s3Providers: Provider = {
  provide: S3_PROVIDER_KEY,
  useFactory: async (): Promise<S3> => {
    return new S3({
      accessKeyId: "Key",
      secretAccessKey: "AccessKey",
    });
  },
};
```

s3.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class S3Service {
  constructor(
     @Inject(S3_PROVIDER_KEY)
     private readonly s3: S3) {}
}
```

You can read more here

[Nestjs custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers)